# How to create an array from multiple Form fields with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a multiple Forms in a single page and i want to create an ajax call for each of them. I was thinking to do it by creating and object of the form's elements name and values and then pass them to the ajax call - by looping each form, so the result i'm looking for is something like this:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" name="name_1">

      <input type="password" name="password_1">

      <input type="email" name="email_1">

      <input type="submit" id="submit_1">    
</form>
```

In Jquery

```
var formInputs = $(form);

for(var i=0; i < formInputs.length; i++){
   var formInputItem = formInputs[i];

   var formSubmitId = formInputItem - get the submit id // not sure how to do it

   $(formSubmitId).click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    // var name = $(formInputItem input[name=name]).val(); not show how to extract the element to achive this 
    var name = $("input[name=name]").val(); 

    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();

    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();

    $.ajax({

       type:'POST',

       url:'/ajaxRequest',

       data:{name:name, password:password, email:email},

       success:function(data){

          alert(data.success);

       }

    });



});
```

}

I know my explanation is a little vague but the idea is simple, 
I have multiple forms, and since each form has a different submit button's id, as well as different input names - the how can i pass the data to the Ajax call?

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Thanks, as you see the important  part is just an examle...i can't get the elements base on their type

Comment: why you dont using form.serialize() ???

Comment: Because i need the name of the inputs....and the id of the the submit button

Comment: I've update the question with better explanation.

Comment: You can write the callback function on the onsubmit event of the form. From that event, you can fetch the relevant field information and send the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your goal. but i hope it helps.

HTML

```
<div id="myForm"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data ='';

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     data += '<form id="form_'+i+'" class="form">';
     data += '<input type="text" id="name_form_'+i+'"><br>';
     data += '<input type="password" id="password_form_'+i+'"><br>';
     data += '<input type="email" id="email_form_'+i+'"><br>';
     data += '<input type="submit" id="submit_form_'+i+'"><br>';
     data += '</form>';
     data += '<br>';
    }
    $("#myForm").html(data);


  $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id); you can alert the form id to check it.
    var name = $("#name_"+id).val();
    var password = $("#password_"+id).val();
    var email = $("#email_"+id).val();

    alert('Name:'+name+' Password:'+password+' Email:'+email);
  });

});
```

As you can see from the javascript i just add the multiple form using for loop. and i add **id+(increment number from loop)** and display it to div first.

and another one i put the class to form tag which is **class="form"**.

and add the onsubmit function.

try: 
https://jsfiddle.net/26rmpewx/57/

Comment: -Thanks for your time, but unfortunately it's not what i'm looking for, i need to extract the input's attributes from the Form, so each Ajax request will get a UNIQE set of Form elements - with the names & id's , so the for loop will produce $('#submit_1'),    $('#submit_2'),  and the same for the inputs.

Comment: you mean you want to get all the values from all forms in one request ? I'm sorry not really good in english.

Comment: JL Barcelona, Thanks, not just their values ( that's the easy part) - i need to get the input's class, or id or any other attribute that will allow me to get it's value from the for loop -i want to address to inputs directly....

Comment: No problem bro.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mkox49w3/3/ can you try this bro i get the attributes.

Comment: JL Barcelona  thanks, it's partially o.k, but unfortunately don't comply a direct solution, perhaps my explanation is bad so i'll continue trying and keep you update -thanks for you time.

Comment: No problem bro anytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name_1">
  <input type="password" name="password_1">
  <input type="email" name="email_1">
  <input type="submit" id="submit_1">    
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {

// Submit form with id function.

  $("#btn_id").click(function() {
      var name = $("#name").val(); 
      var email = $("#email").val();

      $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/ajaxRequest',
      data:{name:name, email:email},
      success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
        }
      });
  });
```

Just try with submit id to click function in jquery like upwards code.

Comment: Thanks....that's a part of my question...how to extract to input attributes (class, name) from the form inputs...

Comment: $("#name").val();. #name mean input name attribute's id

Comment: Sorry buddy, you don't understand the problem, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
 <form>
  <input class="useremail" type="email" name="email_1" value="John@123.com" />
  <input class="username" type="text" name="username_1" value="John" />
  <input type="button" id="submit_1" value="send" />
</form>

<form>
  <input class="useremail" type="email" name="email_2" value="ben@123.com" />
  <input class="username" type="text" name="username_2" value="Ben" />
  <input type="button" id="submit_2" value="send" />
</form>
```

Script.js

```
  $("form").each(function() {
    var userEmail = $(this).find('.useremail').val();
    var userName = $(this).find('.username').val();
    var sendIdButton = $(this).find(':input[type="button"]');

    var ajaxDataObj = {
      name: userName,
      email: userEmail,
    } 

  $('#' + sendIdButton.attr('id')).on('click', function() {
    console.log(ajaxDataObj);

    $.ajax({

       type:'POST',

       url:'/ajaxRequest',

       data:ajaxDataObj,

       success:function(data){

          alert(data.success);

       }

    });
  })
});
```

This will produce the following payload in the ajax request.

name: Ben
email: ben@123.com

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vF7cb/) is an example.